# QtCreator crashes on startup "File Error"

Tags: qt-creator

I am running QtCreator@4.6.1 based on Qt@5.11.0 on Arch Linux@4.16.12-1-ARCH

When starting QtCreator with an active cmake project, the program crashes immidiatley with a notification window titled "File Error". If I delete the folder `<PATH>/.config/QtProject`, it starts without problems.

Starting with `qtcreator -noload Welcome` I can see the a start of cmake server in the shell. No error output in the shell from where I called the project.

How can I debug that behaviour? I really would like to keep my previous projects/sessions and settings.

Comment: It has something to do with the qtcreator folder inside `.config/QtProject`. I renamed mine temporarily and the problem was gone.

Comment: @xsquared that's pretty much what I wrote in my question

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in the same problem. Removing `~/.config/QtProject/qtcreator/helpcollection.qhc` fixed the problem.

Edit: fixed path, forgot "qtcreator"

Comment: Checked my backup and I don't have the file.

Comment: Ah, got you. I think you mean `.config/QtProject/qtcreator/helpcollection.qhc`. That makes it start indeed, but the previous settings are lost anyway, which is probably not avoidable due to compatibility reasons?